# Turning off support for legacy applications in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, filenames

I want to turn off support for legacy applications that don’t understand long filenames in the 8.3 character standard. How can I do this in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

Files that use the 8.3 naming convention can degrade NTFS drive performance. Unless you have a good reason for keeping the 8.3 naming convention intact, such as using 16 bit programs, a performance gain can be achieved by disabling it as follows:

Click on Start -> Run -> Regedit]

Registry Key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
```

Modify/Create the Value Data Type(s) and Value Name(s) as detailed below.

- Data Type: `Dword`
- Value Name: `NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation`

Setting for Value Data: `[0 = Enabled / 1 = Disabled]`

Exit Registry and Reboot

Now any application that requires 8.3 filenames is no longer supported by the operating system, or rather by the file system.